# Adding new data every day in PowerBi with api limit

Tags: api, powerbi, trello

I am trying to get monthly data actions to PowerBI by trello API. This api has limit to 1000 rows. Unfortunately actions in my board is much more then 1000 monthly. API has some variables like before/after so I can take actions for separate days. If I made a query that download data from last day is it possible that PowerBI will add rows to my existing data instead of overwrite?

Comment: No, Power BI is not a database. Make an ETL process to read from the API and save the data in a normal "database" (relational, no-sql, whatever), which has no limit and allows you to perform normal CRUD operations on the data. Then use this as a data source for your Power BI report.